# Why won't Jade indent the code?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I cannot get Jade to indent the code in the for loop correctly:

```
div.container
    - var cell = 0
    - for(var i = 0; i < results.Items.Item.length; i++)
        - if(cell == 0)
            div.row
                div.span3
                    div.cell
                        span #{results.Items.Item[i].ItemAttributes.Title}
        - else
                    div.span3
                        div.cell
                            span #{results.Items.Item[i].ItemAttributes.Title}
        - if(cell < 3)
            - cell++;
        - else
            - cell = 0
```

The code in the else statement does not go inside div.row but instead renders under div.container, or on the same level as div.row. I need the code in the else statement to render inside div.row. How can I get Jade to do this?

What I'm trying to do is to get div.row to render and then after every 4th div.cell (as counted by the cell object) render another div.row

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to do it like this:

```
div.container
    - var cell = 0
    - for(var i = 0; i < results.Items.Item.length; i++)
        div.row
            div.span3
                div.cell
                    span #{results.Items.Item[i].ItemAttributes.Title}

        - if(cell < 3)
            - cell++;
        - else
            div.row
            - cell = 0
```

Comment: I don't follow...that always renders div.row - the goal is to only render div.row when it meets the condition. i need div.cell to indent under div.row but I don't want div.row on every iteration.

Comment: Wait are you saying that you require Jade to output with a particular custom indentation after rendering?  I believe that's impossible.

Comment: It's not really custom - it just doesn't make any sense that you cannot indent in an else statement because an else statement never ends until it meets something else on the same level as the else statement. So how do you indent if the else statement never ends?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  Check my edit, does that perform what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

use curly braces "{" and "}"

```
div.container
        - var cell = 0
        - for(var i = 0; i < results.Items.Item.length; i++){
            - if(cell == 0){
                div.row
                    div.span3
                        div.cell
                            span #{results.Items.Item[i].ItemAttributes.Title}
            - }
            - else{
                        div.span3
                            div.cell
                                span #{results.Items.Item[i].ItemAttributes.Title}
            - }
            - if(cell < 3)
                - cell++
            - else
                - cell = 0
        - }
```